# Can't perform regular sudo commands, have to use su now

Tags: sudo, root, users, unprivileged

I'm an Ubuntu newbie I just installed 10.10 and I don't know what I did but now to perform actions that required `sudo` privileges (open synaptic, mount device, run apt-get install, etc) the OS won't let me saying I don't have enough privileges, for example when I try to `sudo apt-get install` it tells me:

```
myusername is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

So I have to log in as su to do any on these things. I didn't have to do this before, I just used the regular root privileges but as I said I must have changed something unintentionally.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you post the output of the `id` command (i.e. groups you are a member of)?

Comment: I tried but it said sudo: /etc/sudoers is mode 0644, should be 0440 sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard setup requires all sudoers to be in the admin group. You either dropped out of that group or are using an account that never had this group membership.

As root, add yourself to the admin group

```
addgroup myusername admin
```

And try again. If this didn't do the trick then something in your sudo setup is not as it should be. Maybe let us have a look at /etc/sudoers. I would expect there to be the last line:

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Comment: Thanks DsSAR, adding myself as an admin fixed the issue, I guess I must have done something to drop myself out of the group since ubuntu auto-adds the first account as an admin I think.

Comment: Yes it does; Don't mean to scare you but keep an eye out for more privilege weirdness. Make sure all accounts on your machine are properly password protected and only accounts that need to have admin access. You can check using 'grep admin /etc/group' which will list all users that are part of admin (and probably also lpadmin, but that's not relevant here)

Comment: Thanks, it's a fresh ubuntu install so it just has me for now.